# No BT:LE notifications on for characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working with bluetooth in my android application,

I have discovered my device, connected and started discovering services. I am attempting to receive notifications from characteristics but am having no joy. I know the device is sending as i have similar cod working on my iOS app with the same bluetooth hardware. this is on my OnServiceDiscovered code

```
    public override void OnServicesDiscovered (BluetoothGatt gatt, GattStatus status)

    {

        foreach (var service in gatt.Services) {

            foreach (var characteristic in service.Characteristics.ToList()) {

                var response = gatt.SetCharacteristicNotification (characteristic, true);

            }

    }
}
```

I am hitting the loop for several characteristics and services but i never get a callback to the following method

```
    public override void OnCharacteristicChanged (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)

    {

        var id = characteristic.Uuid.ToString ();

    }
```

Am i missing something? I essentially want to subscribe to all services and attributes and receive notifications..